# Can someone please explain this mysql statement to me

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to learn mysql on my own by debugging a php program. However I am now stuck. I do not understand what this particular statement is or what it does:

```
$StatusRequirements = array(
    array(80*1024*1024*1024, 0.50, 0.40),
    array(60*1024*1024*1024, 0.50, 0.30),
    array(50*1024*1024*1024, 0.50, 0.20),
    array(40*1024*1024*1024, 0.40, 0.10),
    array(30*1024*1024*1024, 0.30, 0.05),
    array(20*1024*1024*1024, 0.20, 0.0),
    array(10*1024*1024*1024, 0.15, 0.0),
    array(5*1024*1024*1024,  0.10, 0.0)
);
$DB->query("UPDATE users_main SET RequiredStatus=0.50 WHERE Access>100*1024*1024*1024");
```

In simple English I understand it like this:

Database Query Update users_main and set required status to 0.50 where access is greater than 100 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024.

What I don't understand is the significance of the numbers 100*1024*1024*1024.

Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: There's no intrinsic significance, `100*1024*1024*1024` could be easily be substituted with `104857600`. Either the developer was too lazy to do the calculation or they tought `100*1024*1024*1024` would have been more significant for someone to understand it (in this case one immediately thinks about it as 100 GiB)

Comment: So the statement would translate to: Database Query Update users_main and set required status to 0.50 where access is greater than 100gb?

Comment: If that makes sense in the context of the application... `100*1024*1024*1024` made me instanly think of 100GiB (mind that those are not the same as GB by the way)

Comment: Thanks kos. I'll see if that helps. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we were doing a code inspection and reading code, one way to say this would be:

"In the table `users_main`, update the `RequiredStatus` field to 0.50 for rows that have the `Access` field greater than 10G."

Comment: Agreed. It looks like a rising scale such that the value is set based on access values. The statement in question appears to refer to the required status needed for any values greater than those in the list.  The meaning of the list of values is curretly opaque and from our point of view may as well have been 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it's definitely clearer now. But if I might ask why is it 10gb. If you convert bytes to gigabytes wouldn't 100*1024*1024*1024 = 100gb?  Because it seems to me that for the purpose of the application 10gb would be way more reasonable than 100gb. Or is it something I'm missing?

Comment: Also I am unable to understand, at what point is the array called?

Comment: The array is not actually used.  It's just initialized.  Perhaps it's used later on ?

Comment: Thanx Scott. Your explanation helped me to figure it out. Off to tinker with it. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

don't get confused with the 10*1024*1024*1024 it is just parsing a larger no.In my guess it may be conversion of bit to gb  or something .The query is fine

Comment: You're right I'm sure it's definitely bit to gb. That was huge in helping me to get it.

Comment: do you get it know?? or are u still confused??

Comment: I understand now what the numbers mean so that I may edit them, but I don't understand how or when the array is called.

Comment: There is no any use of array that you have stated above .The array defined there may be used for any other purpose in your overall code that you have not described here so for the update query array is of no use. If you don't understand what array is then please study about array and if not revert to me I can make you clear.

Comment: Thanks Sagar. It's appreciated.